# PHP - variables not joining properly

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to join several variables to create a file path. The file path changes each day and have set it up accordingly. The problem is that after I join them together they they delete them self and leave only the date. Here is the code

```
$filepath2 = "/data/";
$date = date(Ymd);
$unit = $_GET;
$part1 = strval($unit);
$part2 = strval($date);
$part3 = ".txt";
$filepath = $filepath2 + $part1 + $part2 + $part3;
echo $filepath;
```

The echo just comes back with 20120713 (the date). Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Shouldnt you do `date("Ymd")` instead of w/o quotes?

Comment: it works this that way? if that is the better way to phrase it then i will (Im quite new to php haha)

Comment: From PHP docs: `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`. Meaning, the first parameter needs to be a string. Link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This is how you would CAT in javascript ( for future searchers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To concatenate strings in PHP you are not supposed to use `+` but the concatenation operator; the dot.

Correction of the relevant line in your snippet:

```
$filepath = $filepath2 . $part1 . $part2 . $part3;
```

---

**You can read more about string operators by following the link below:**

- **[php.net PHP: String Operators - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)**

Comment: @Nicholas please remember to flag the post as accepted when that option is available to mark the question as solved.

Comment: @refp I will accept the answer but it dosn't let you straight after the question is posted, you have to wait 15 min. I will in 5 min :)